# How to apply a function to multiple PySpark dataframes in parallel

Tags: python, pyspark, parallel-processing

I'm kinda new to pyspark and I'm trying to construct a datawarehouse with it. So baiscally I've a lot o dataframes where I need to apply the same function to all of them. I made a simple version of my code to you to undestand what I mean. My simple code looks like this:

```
df_list = [spark.createDataFrame([(1, "foo"), (2, "bar")], ["id", "name"]),
           spark.createDataFrame([(3, "baz"), (4, "qux")], ["id", "name"])]

# define the function to apply to each DataFrame
def my_function(df):
    # do some processing on the DataFrame
    df = df.filter("id > 1")
    return df

# Create an RDD from the list of DataFrames
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(df_list)

# Apply the function to each DataFrame in parallel
results = rdd.flatMap(lambda df: my_function(df)).collect()

# Print the modified DataFrames
for df in df_list:
    df.show()
```

but for some reason I'm getting the error:

```
cannot pickle '_thread.RLock' object
```

I did some research and I can't understand why I'm getting this error, once, according what I've found on Google, pypskar dataframes are serializable objects.

I also tried using foreach and map functions, but also didn't worked.

Can anybody help me here?
thank you in advance!

Comment: The function you want to apply will be the same to all DataFrame? Do they have the same schema? If so, you can Union all DFs and then apply the function, it will be executed in parallel since Spark will distribute the data between the workers.

Comment: Actually, the dataframes doesn't have the same Schema so I can't apply a union function on them

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
df_list = [spark.createDataFrame([(1, "foo"), (2, "bar")], ["id", "name"]),
           spark.createDataFrame([(3, "baz"), (4, "qux")], ["id", "name"])]
```

***Case 1: If you want all  the DataFrame to be as it is***

1. Iterate through the list
2. Perform `transform()` function on your DataFrame to chain any transformation `(filter("id > 1"))` with it.
3. Store the result in a list

```
filtered_df_list = [ df.transform(lambda df: df.filter("id > 1")) for df in df_list]
```

4. Just iterate through the `filtered_df_list` to perform some action

```
for df in mdf_list:
    df.show()
```

Output:

```
+---+----+
| id|name|
+---+----+
|  2| bar|
+---+----+

+---+----+
| id|name|
+---+----+
|  3| baz|
|  4| qux|
+---+----+
```

***Case 2: If you want to combine all DataFrames and perform transformation on top it*** using this method as mentioned by ***Kevin***

1. Create an Empty DataFrame

```
empty_df = spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), schema="id INT, name STRING")
```

2. Iterate through the `df_list` to perform `union()` transformation to combine all the existing DataFrames with it.

```
for df in df_list:
    empty_df = empty_df.union(df)
```

3. Apply `filter()` transformation on top of it

```
empty_df.filter("id > 1").show()
```

Output:

```
+---+----+
| id|name|
+---+----+
|  2| bar|
|  3| baz|
|  4| qux|
+---+----+
```